# Get Process Handle in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, process, windows-api-code-pack

I am trying to get a process handle without success, I have read a lot about that but don't know why I cannot achieve it.

This is what I am doing:

[image]

```
$handle = $Kernel32::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 4548)
```

I am doing it with admin rights, it seems like it doesn't like the `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` parameter. Any idea?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code (or errors) unless there is absolutely no other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't recognize the symbolic constants you're trying to use there. Use the numeric values instead. For `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` that should be 1056763 or 0x00101ffb (and you also need `$false` instead of `FALSE`). However, you probably [shouldn't be using `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151210-00/?p=92451) in the first place.

Try with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (numeric value 4096 or 0x1000):

```
$handle = $Kernel32::OpenProcess(0x1000, $false, 4548)
```